# Computing the homology group of $\mathbb{R^n \setminus S^{n-1}}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am trying to compute the singular homology group of $\mathbb{R^n \setminus S^{n-1}}$. I tried using the simplices but it is getting complicated. I think I need to use Mayer-Vietoris sequence but can anyone help me with the solution.

I was thinking of using the fact that $H_0(\mathbb{R^n \setminus S^{n-1}})=H_0(*) \oplus \overline{H}_0(\mathbb{R^n \setminus S^{n-1}})$ and $H_j(\mathbb{R^n \setminus S^{n-1}})=\overline{H}_j(\mathbb{R^n \setminus S^{n-1}})$ for all $j >0$ , where $\overline{H}$ is the reduced homology group. But I am stuck in this way as well. Please help me with this idea.

Thanks

Comment: Think geometrically. $\mathbb R^n\setminus\mathbb S^{n-1}$ is a union of two familiar spaces.

Comment: @Niven do you mean the interior and the exterior? I have not proved jordan seperation theorem

Comment: I do. I understood $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ to be the usual unit sphere inside $\mathbb R^n$, in which case you do not need Jordan separation since everything is fairly concrete. If you are working with a general embedding of $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ in $\mathbb R^n$, then this basically amounts to proving Jordan separation, and you are right that you will want to use Mayer-Vietoris. Is it the case that $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ is not necessarily the unit sphere?

Comment: so what exactly am I supposed to use as $A$ and $B$ for applying mayer-vietoris?

Comment: @GraduateStudent There are two pretty obvious parts to your space. What about using those?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\sm\setminus\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}\renewcommand\S{\mathbb S}\newcommand\redhom{\widetilde H}\newcommand\into{\hookrightarrow}\newcommand\D{\mathbb D}\newcommand\Z{\mathbb Z}$
Assuming you really mean to compute the homology of $\R^n\sm h(\S^{n-1})$ where $h:\S^{n-1}\into\R^n$ is an arbitrary embedding, I think this is a somewhat involved endeavor, so I am giving less than an answer but more than a comment.

If you look at the beginning of section 2.B of Hatcher, he proves that, for $h:\S^{n-1}\into\S^n$ an embedding,
$$\redhom_i(\S^n\sm h(\S^{n-1}))=\begin{cases}\Z&i=0\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
For brevity's sake, we'll take this as given. Going from this to homology where $\R^n$ replaces $\S^n$ is another (now simple) application of Mayer-Vietoris.

So say now we have $h:\S^{n-1}\into\R^n$ and write $\S^n=\R^n\cup\{\infty\}$. Since $h(\S^{n-1})\subset\R^n$ is compact (in particular, bounded), we can find an open disk $U\subset\S^n$ around $\infty$ so that $U\cap h(\S^{n-1})=\emptyset$. Now, let $A=\R^n\sm h(\S^{n-1})$ and $B=U\sm h(\S^{n-1})=U\simeq*$, so $A\cup B=\S^n\sm h(\S^{n-1})$ and $A\cap B=U\cap\R^n=U\sm\{\infty\}\simeq\S^{n-1}$. Applying Mayer-Vietoris to $A\cup B=\S^n\sm h(\S^{n-1})$ very quickly gives
$$\redhom_i(\R^n\sm h(\S^{n-1}))=\begin{cases}\Z\oplus\Z&i=0\text{ and }n=1\\\Z&i=0,n-1\text{ and }n>1\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
In the end, you can find the answer to your question in Proposition 2B.1 of Hatcher, and then you have to do a little more work to replace $\S^n$ with $\R^n$.

Comment: What is the use of an embedding $h$ here? Clearly $S^{n-1} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $ \mathbb{R}^n \setminus S^{n-1}$ is well-defined

Comment: This is what I asked you about in the comments of your question. If $S^{n-1}\subset\mathbb R^n$ in the standard way (i.e. as the unit sphere) in your question, then you do not need anything fancy, and you do not even need Mayer-Vietoris. You know what the space $\mathbb R^n\setminus S^{n-1}$ is and the homology of its components is easily determined.
Since you responded there asking about applying Mayer-Vietoris, I took this to mean that $S^{n-1}$ is actually embedded in some potentially non-standard way in your problem. This is what complicated things and why there's this $h$ hanging around.